# How Do I Search Values By Joining Three Tables

Tags: php

The Below Code Joins Three Different Tables `post_img_text`,`user`,and `trend`

```
|post_img_text  |  user     |  trend   

 postID  
 userID         |  userID   |  trendID
 postImg        |  userName |  userID
                            |  trendName

<?php 
$sql =  "SELECT * FROM post_img_text RIGHT JOIN user ON post_img_text.userID=user.userID LEFT JOIN trend ON user.userID=trend.userID
WHERE user.userID!='".$page_owner."'  AND (userName LIKE '%".$searchVal."%' OR trendName LIKE '%".$searchVal."%')  GROUP BY user.userID";
$res3 = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($row2=mysql_fetch_assoc($res3)){
?>
```

**What I want?**

If i search userName or trendName from the database So basically i want result of table `user` in one row and result of table `trend` in next/other row and

NOTE: Don't want to concat this

**Example:** When we search name on fb then we get users account in one row and pages in next row so basically i want like this in single query

Comment: **JOIN** is made to retrieve data combining from different tables (by _joining_).

Comment: Purpose of using **JOIN** is to get combined result-set from different tables.

Comment: Then How Can I Do What I want ?

Comment: Run over two loops to get different result-set from different tables.

Comment: you mean to say in while loop their should be another loop

Comment: Yeah first loop to get the users only and second loop to get related data of particular user.

Comment: can u give me query for this im confuse in loop in loop